# A question from Isaac's book "Finite group theory" about Transfer theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, transfer-theory

Let $G$ be finite group and suppose that $P\in Sylp_p(G)$ and that $g\in P$ has order $p$. If $g\in G',$ but $g\notin P'$, Show  that $g^t\in P'$ for some element $t\in G$ with $t\notin P$.($5.B1$)

Let $\overline V$ be the transfer map from $G$ to $P/P'$. As $g\in G'$, $ \overline {V(g)}=\bar 1$.

By the transfer evaluation lemma, $$V(g)=\prod_{t\in T_0} g^t \in P'.$$

Thus, the product of some conjugates of $g$ lies in $P'$.

But I do not see that it causes $g^t\in P'$ for some $t$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this right? It could not possibly be true if $P'=1$. For example, let $G=S_3$ with $p=3$. Then for $1 \ne g \in P \in {\rm Syl}_3(G)$, we have $g \in G'$ but $g \not\in P'$.

Comment: As I assumed that question is true , I did not look for counter example. Your example seems to be a counter exaple.

Comment: I wonder whether it should have been prove $g^t \in P$ for some $t \not\in P$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Yes it can be proven $g^t\in P$ for some $t\notin P$. Maybe, Isaacs want to ask this one and write $P'$ instead of $P$.